# Nav 2 on Ros foxy or humble

Tags: ros2, nav2, nvidia

I am a beginner in robotics and have a few questions and problems that I could use help with. First, I have a robotics competition in a few weeks, and I have a Jetson Nano running ROS. I was using ROS 2 Foxy and had an RP Lidar for navigation. I've encountered some trouble with the setup process. Many people in various forums are stating that Nav2 only works properly with ROS Humble and Ubuntu 22.04. Unfortunately, my Jetson Nano can only run Ubuntu 20.04 and either Foxy or Galactic. Could anyone recommend a solution to this or any tutorials or courses that use Nav2 with ROS Galactic or Humble? Also, do I only need a lidar to make my robot move autonomously in a room? I just want to move it a few feet in each direction, and I have motor encoders. Additionally, are there any tips anyone could provide to make my project easier or anything I need to add?

Answer (score 0):

I've just gone through this process for a AGX Jetson Xavier NX platform running Jetpack 5.0 with an RP Lidar system.

I ran into issues using the NAV2 stack alongside Foxy, and solved them by migrating to Humble. The ROS2 buildfarm only build Humble packages for Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy, but lucky for us, NVIDIA has us covered with the Isaac ROS Buildfarm, which builds packages for Ubuntu 20.04.

You can find the instructions here: https://nvidia-isaac-ros.github.io/getting_started/isaac_ros_buildfarm_cdn.html

Comment: This seems like a good solution but Jetson Nano doesn't support jetpack 5.0 would this be a issue?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally ran into this issue but I would try to delete what you have installed of the nav2 stack and reinstall by cloning [The foxy-devel branch](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/tree/foxy-devel) of nav2 directly into your foxy workspace and build.